# How can I identify Mobile Speaker issue and how to reduce the noise while Music is playing in Speaker?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Grand2.Recently I'm facing Noise(with some vibration) while listening to Music in Mobile's Speaker.How to confirm that it's mobile speaker issue and also how to fix it? Kindly help understanding it.I'm using KITKAT version of Andriod.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is behind the phone speaker side there were dust particles with little Oil which caused the phone to have noise and vibration rather than flawless Music:) So be careful in presence of oil.Never allow oil to have contact with Mobile.